# Magento 2 Configurable option not showing my custom theme

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-options

Magento 2 Configurable Swatch option option not showing my custom theme but it's working in Default theme

**My Default theme**
[image]

**Custom Theme**
[image]

Product Details page it's working fine only problem is listing page. How to i fix this? What mistake i made here

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>

<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
      $parent_category = $current_category->getParentCategory();
      $Category_Name =  $current_category->getName();
      //echo $parent_category->getName(); ?>
      <h4 class="groceries-txt"><?php echo $Category_Name;?></h4>
    <div class="category-section products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <!-- <ol class="products list items product-items"> -->
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-block ">' : '</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-block">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info category-cnt sub-category mtc-height " data-container="product-grid" style="height: 394px;">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?php //echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php
                            //$image = 'category_page_grid' or 'category_page_list';
                            $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

                            $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(100)->getUrl();
                        ?>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $_product->getName()?>" />
                        </figure>

                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                            $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                            $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
                            $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
                        ?>
                        <?php if($specialprice){?>
                        <div class="offer-lable">
                        <?php
                            $today = time();
                            $price = $_product->getPrice();
                            if($price){
                                $sale = round((($price-$specialprice)/$price)*100);
                            }
                            if ($specialprice) {
                                if ($today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)) { ?>
                                    <div class="label-product label-sale">
                                        <span class="sale-product-icon">
                                            <?php if($sale) { echo $sale.'% Off'; } else {echo __('Sale');} ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }
                            }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');?>">
                               <h5>
                                <?php //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                <?php
                                    $prod_name = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                                   $count_str = strlen($prod_name);
                                   if ($count_str < 30) {
                                       echo $prod_name;
                                   } else {
                                       $offset = 0;
                                       $length = 20;  
                                       $prod_name = html_entity_decode($prod_name);                    
                                       echo htmlentities(mb_substr($prod_name,0,$length,'utf-8')). "...";;                        
                                   }
                                   ?>

                                </h5>
                            </a>

                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>

                        <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>


                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                    class="action btn-cart">
                                                <span>

                                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                        <?php echo $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml(); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <!-- </ol> -->
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php /*if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; */?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How i will fix this?

Comment: Did u verify if there is no js conflicts? If you are using any jquery then you need to mention jQuery.noConflict() from this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991404/configurable-product-options-not-showing-the-options-on-frontend

Comment: No Js conflict i checked

Comment: I think you should post a bit of your template code: layout and template involved in category view, maybe you are missing some block. Another thing I assume your template inherits from luma or blank right?

Comment: i am using <parent>Magento/blank</parent>

Comment: which theme have you used? Please share your list.phtml file code to debug your issue.

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: Have you made custom theme based on parent luma theme, Right? and also working in default theme.

Comment: Above code is working fine for me. Please check you have set style display none for swatches.

Comment: No display none that div itself it's not calling in my inspect element

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya my swatch js not calling in that page how i call

Comment: I think by default its working and i have check your above code and in my case its working fine. have you any changes for your theme?

Comment: No change how we can call that js

Comment: @Kothari You forgot to remove */ from <?php endif; */?> second last line

Comment: @Magento2, can you help me to apply swatch on the the product detail page? How can I achieve the feature to change image when the user changes the color of the product? Please help. I am really in need to get help for this.

Answer (score 6):

Step 1.First of all Edit your custom listing layout file

`Vender/Module/view/frontend/layout/custom_listing.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="main">
        <block class="CutomBlockClass"  name="cutome.block.name" before="-" cacheable="false" template = "custom.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.custom" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer> 
    <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers.custom">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="custom/category/product/cutomeSwetchFile.phtml" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">category-custom</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

**Note:** block name of `category.product.type.details.renderers.custom` and `<referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers.custom">` should be same.

Step: 2 add css file in your custom layout file:

```
<css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
```

Step:3 Vender/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom/category/product/cutomeSwetchFile.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable */ ?>
<div class="swatch-opt-<?php echo $block->getType(); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {
        $('.swatch-opt-<?php echo $block->getType(); ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').SwatchRenderer({
            selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
            onlySwatches: true,
            enableControlLabel: false,
            numberToShow: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code for this feature?