# In my custom theme swatch option not display in category page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, swatches, custom-theme, category-page

In my custom theme   swatch option not  display in category page in magento 2
configuration option is  not display in the category page

refer image : https://prnt.sc/nvegd1

Comment: Are you use any custom theme?

Comment: s, i m using a custom theme

Comment: Wich theme are you using?

Comment: its our own theme

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175268/magento-2-configurable-option-not-showing-my-custom-theme?rq=1

Comment: i was already tried that, it was not working